# Is there known issues for JWS applications on Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows-7, java-web-start

I've got a JWS application which works perfectly on Windows XP but fails to start on Windows 7. The problem is that Java is not able to find the native library which is embeded in a JAR bundle:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xxxxxx.dll in java.library.path
```

The problem is not in the DLL (missing dependency for example) because if I put it in C:\windows\system32\, the JWS application works.

So I want to know if there are some known issues which can explain that Java is not able to load/find a well-served native library on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, the problem was not due to Windows 7 but was related to an incorrect signature of a JAR file.